# ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.PORTRAIT_UP) is not working on IOS

Tags: react-native, expo, screen-orientation

I have react native expo and I'm trying to lock the screen on portrait, so I downloaded ScreenOrientation. I putted this: `ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.PORTRAIT_UP)`
on an useEffect and for Android it works perfectly fine. However, when I try on an Ipad, it doesn't work. How can I sole this?

Comment: Facing the same issue - expo SDK 43. For me, it is working in expo CLI but in RN CLI it doesn't. Found any solution?